# Why ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Context, String) doesn't requires API 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

When I use `checkSelfPermission(String)`, Android Studio shows: `"Call requires API level 23".`

When I use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Context, String)` then Android Studio doesn't show any errors.

Can you explain me that?

Comment: That's what the `Compat` means - compatibility, with older API levels. It does the necessary checks for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Compat` classes (ActivityCompat, ViewCompat etc) are just a neat way to avoid littering your code with API version checks. If there is a method that does not exists for all APIs or that has changed it's signature, the Compat class will make sure that the appropriate actions are taken for each API version. I suggest you take a look in source code to see how it works:

ActivityCompat:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/37ae8a0/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.java